# How to give X, Y, Z different values from the same math.random() function?

Tags: lua, roblox

Basically what i want is:

```lua
local X, Y, Z = math.random()
```

Without assigning each value to `math.random()`:

```lua
local X, Y, Z = math.random(), math.random(), math.random()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function that does that for you:

```lua
local function rand(n)
    local res = {}
    for i = 1, n do
        table.insert(res, math.random())
    end
    return table.unpack(res)
end
```

And call it like that:

```lua
local X, Y, Z = rand(3) -- Get 3 random numbers
print(X, Y, Z)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to build an intermediate table though; you can simply write a recursive function to generate the vararg:

```lua
local function rand(n)
    if n == 1 then return math.random() end
    return math.random(), rand(n-1)
end
```

shorter (and possibly faster); also doesn't create a garbage table; even better, you could generalize this:

```
local function rep(func, n)
    if n == 1 then return func() end
    return func(), rep(func, n-1)
end
```

then use as follows:

```
local x, y, z = rep(math.random, 3)
```

Comment: _"and possibly faster"_ Why?

Comment: @Zakk because your function does more work: it first builds a table (using `table.insert` calls which index `_G` and `table`) only to unpack it; I'm not quite sure how this would perform in Roblox, but in the expected use case of few random variables (~ 10 in my benchmarking) my function performs better (at least when using LuaJIT): `0.142702` vs 
`0.512701` for LuaJIT, `1.00099` vs `2.280177` for PUC Lua 5.1, all numbers in seconds of CPU time spent (`os.clock()`), benchmarking code used is `for i = 1, 1e6 do local _ = rand(10) end`.

Comment: For the record, your solution is ~4.5x faster on PUC-Lua with minimal change across 5.1 to 5.4. (FX6300 @ 4Ghz). Your recursive solution takes around 400ms to make 3 random numbers 1,000,000 times, @Zakk solution takes around 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`math.random()` only returns one number, but you can just set one variable to be the result of `math.random()`, then set the others based on some mathematical operation of the variable you assigned to be `math.random()`.

For instance:

```
local x = math.random()
local y = x * 5
local z = y - x
```

`y` and `z` are still "random" values because they're indirectly generated from `math.random()`.

Comment: But in this case `y` and `z` are `x`-dependant.

Comment: @Zakk, yes, hence the "random" in quotes.